# Get total number of the black and white pixels in bitmap image separately

Tags: c#, image, bitmap

I am trying to write a code that goes through my image and counts all the pixels line by line and tells me how many white and how many black pixels are in my image? (Assuming my image is made of a black character against white background)

```
var backgroundPixels = 0;

     for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
                {
                    if (bmp.GetPixel(x, y).Equals(Color.White))
                    {
                        backgroundPixels++;
                    }
                }

            }
            label3.Text = Convert.ToString(backgroundPixels);
```

I am having problem as the code doesn’t work for some reason. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/193440), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Could you describe more in detail what the currently observed behavior is, then?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Does it crash? Do the values not correspond to what it's actually there? Does it not parse all the pixels?

Comment: Try using `R` `G` and `B` of `bmp.GetPixel(x, y)`

Comment: has the "doesn’t work" some name? lets say exception?

Comment: You can play a bit with MS Paint and create a control image to see if it really iterates all pixels and if the values are correctly incremented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you  use `==` or `Equals` you are not comparing the value of ARGB byte by byte because the '==' operator is done like this

```
     public static bool operator ==(Color left, Color right)
        {
          if (left.value != right.value || (int) left.state != (int) right.state || (int) left.knownColor != (int) right.knownColor)
            return false;
          if (left.name == right.name)
            return true;
          if (left.name == null || right.name == null)
            return false;
          else
            return left.name.Equals(right.name);
        }
```

following  is how is done the `Equals` Method in .net

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
      if (obj is Color)
      {
        Color color = (Color) obj;
        if (this.value == color.value && (int) this.state == (int) color.state && (int) this.knownColor == (int) color.knownColor)
        {
          if (this.name == color.name)
            return true;
          if (this.name == null || color.name == null)
            return false;
          else
            return this.name.Equals(this.name);
        }
      }
      return false;
    }
```

to overcome your issue you  should convert to ARGB using  the [`ToArgb()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.DRAWING.COLOR.TOARGB%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true) function  which send 32-bit of the current  color

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            int whiteColor = 0;
            int blackColor = 0; 
            for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
                {
                    Color color = bmp.GetPixel(x, y); 

                    if (color.ToArgb()==Color.White.ToArgb())
                    {
                        whiteColor++;  
                    }

                    else
                        if (color.ToArgb() == Color.White.ToArgb())
                        {
                            blackColor++; 
                        }
                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work because you are comparing Color structs:

```
if (bmp.GetPixel(x, y).Equals(Color.White))
```

the "Name" member of the struct is not going to be "White" on your pixel, it will be a string containing the hex value "ffffff", so the objects are different even though the ARGB values are the same. You need to compare the ARGB values. The Color struct is stupid like that.

```
if (bmp.GetPixel(x, y).ToArgb().Equals(Color.White.ToArgb()))
```

The other possibility is that your pixels aren't actually black and white but greyscale.

Comment: so how should i first get a clear black and white bitmap image? (not greyscale)

Comment: You don't even need to, you can just check if the values are higher or lower than some threshold, instead of checking whether they are 255 or 0. For example, <= 127 = black, > 127 = white. If it's greyscale all components should be the same so you can just check just one of the colors.

Comment: svinja: thank you for your comment, i actually need to convert the image to black and white for the next phase of my work, could you please let me know if you no how to do that?thnks

Answer (score 1):

The `Equals()` method compares more than just your ARGB color.
This means that a color with RGB=0,0,0 (black) is *not* the same as `Color.Black`.

Try using the following to compare:

```
if (bmp.GetPixel(x, y).ToArgb().Equals(Color.White.ToArgb()))
```

or

```
if (bmp.GetPixel(x, y).ToArgb() == Color.White.ToArgb())
```